# Java admin rights (UAC)

Tags: java, uac, admin

My application consists of a server a and client interface. I want the client to be able to request the server to write a registry key. Now i did my research on libraries for java that do that and i found a few. The problem lies with admin rights. When i run a simple java program to read from the registry i get an error that informs me that i don't have sufficient rights. I am guessing it has to do with UAC in vista and 7 but the same problem also occurs when i run the program from windows XP.

Is there a way to run my server program with elevated rights so that when the client requests a registry update, the server will run it with no problems? (right click run as admin is not an option i'm afraid)

**EDIT :**

What my question actually boils down to is whether there is a way to launch a jar file as an executable with elevated permissions. I mean something as simple as that should be available no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a "hacky" solution to this problem. I create a shortcut to the java.exe program, modify it's target to pass parameters that launch my jar and then simply tick "Run as administrator". But i still think that there should be an option to launch with elevated rights for jars...

Answer (score 0):

There is always the [runas](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/runas.mspx?mfr=true) command.

Comment: this won't work because of two reasons. first it needs the specific admin name for the command options and then it needs to type the password in a blind command line interface... i need some way to invoke the UAC dialog on vista/7 or simply run with admin rights in XP

Comment: You will need an administrator name regardless for XP.  You can prevent it from asking for the password (except for the first time) using the `/savecred` switch.